# Where online can I find the oldest Sidur?

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, internet, prayer-book

I am looking for the oldest sidur you can find and read online. I mean a scanned version of course. If possible before 1000 Modern Era.

Ps: I am not looking for something in a museum since I want to read in it.

Comment: If partial siddurim qualify, if you look through the online Cairo Geniza for siddur-fragments (at [Oxford](http://genizah.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/search/results_all?quick=siddur&start=10) and [Cambridge](http://cudl.lib.cam.ac.uk/search?keyword=siddur)), I suspect you will eventually see the oldest siddur online, but I don't know how you would recognize it as such; they are not clearly dated. (Many fragments are simply tagged "Date of Creation: 6th-19th century." They do identify the material they are printed on, so limiting your search to vellum may help.)

Answer (score 1):

I admit that this is not a precise answer to your question but it may give you hope.

[The Jewish Daily Forward](http://forward.com/articles/184640/-year-old-jewish-prayer-book-is-unveiled/#ixzz2gIITGaKP) carried an article about

> AUSTIN, TEX. — A 1,200-year-old parchment Jewish prayer book that is
>   billed as the oldest in existence was introduced Sept. 27 by a
>   prominent private collector of Biblical artifacts.
>
> Full research on the book will be published next year or in early 2015
>   with the Netherlands-based Brill, edited by Emanuel Tov, a bible
>   professor at Hebrew University of Jerusalem, and Jerry Pattengale,
>   executive director of the Green Scholars Initiative, according to
>   Green.

[The Times of Israel](http://www.timesofisrael.com/worlds-oldest-known-siddur-unveiled-in-jerusalem/) has a report about the time the siddur was exhibited in Jerusalem last autumn with a picture of one of the pages.

Its final home will be [The Green Collection](http://greencollection.org/)  and its website says that

> Guests will be able to experience this collection year-round
>   when Museum of the Bible opens its 430,000-square-foot museum in
>   Washington, D.C., scheduled to open in 2017.

Comment: Thanks. Although that was not exactly what I was looking for.